# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Autoscaler, key ""

Tags: azure-diagnostics

**Exception:**
Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Autoscaler, key ""

**Stack Trace:**
  at IUSCRM.WebRole.OnStart() in D:\Windows Azure Cloud\Samples\Windows Azure HelloWorld Sample\C#\HelloWorld_WebRole\WebRole.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRole(RoleType roleType)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__0()

**Inner Exception:**
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Autoscaler", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Autoscaler,(none)
  Resolving parameter "dataPointsStoreStorageAccountConnectionString" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Autoscaler(System.String dataPointsStoreStorageAccountConnectionString, System.String dataPointsTableName, System.TimeSpan ruleEvaluationRate, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Rules.IRulesStore rulesStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceModel.IServiceInformationStore serviceInformationStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.DataPointsCollection.IDataPointsCollectorsProvider dataPointsCollectorsProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.IExecutionLease executionLease, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Logging.ILogger logger, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Scaling.IServiceManagementRequestTracker tracker, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Scaling.IScaler scaler)
    Resolving System.String,(none)

**Source:**
Microsoft.Practices.Unity

**Stack Trace:**
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49

**Inner Exception:**
The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

**Source:**
Microsoft.Practices.Unity

**Stack Trace:**
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext context, SelectedConstructor selectedConstructor)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)
   at BuildUp_Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.Autoscaler(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)

For the past two days i have struck with this exception, so some one please help...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution  for the above asked question which as follows,

In the absence of an app.config working with the RoleEntryPoint implementation in a web role, a well-known workaround many people have taken, has been to include a WaIISHost.exe.config file in their project. The background on this approach, and internal details can be found here. If you are using this approach, and have moved to the recent version of the Windows Azure SDK, version 1.8, you may have noticed this no longer works as it did with the previous versions.

We recently had some customers using this approach, now migrating to Windows Azure SDK 1.8, only to find that their application settings in WaIISHost.exe.config were no longer available to the code running in the RoleEntryPoint implementation. No, the process name has not changed and at some later point I will find some time to go in to more of the details that we have found changed. For now I just wanted to provide yet another workaround that works with SDK 1.8, for those of you that may have run in to this. There are situations, such as with some 3rd party dependencies that prevent us from moving all of our configuration settings in to .cscfg, or even to code, and some settings really don’t need to be there anyway.

The workaround. It's actually quite simple.

Basically we rename the WaIISHost.exe.config to the name of the output assembly containing the RoleEntryPoint implementation in your web project, with the addition of the .config extension, of course. So for a web application project named "MyApp.Web" and assembly name of "MyApp.Web" we renamed the WaIISHost.exe.config to MyApp.Web.dll.config. If you are going to add this file to a new project, don’t forget to set the “Copy to Output Directory” property to “Copy Always”.

Following link is the source of this solution,

http://www.fullscale180.com/post/2012/11/08/WaIISHostexeconfig-in-Web-Roles-does-not-work-in-Windows-Azure-SDK-18.aspx